# Selenium - clicking on button not working?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i try to click on the "Top Crossing" button on this site:
https://sensortower.com/ios/rankings/top/iphone/us/games?date=2021-07-12
(the button seems to be available only when the width is set to a lower value - so i tried to change the windows size with the following statement which seems to work fine:

```
driver.set_window_size(600,1000)
```

this is the full code with which i try to press the button

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x800")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')   
options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])      
path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
if sys.platform == "win32": cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
elif sys.platform == "linux": cd = '/chromedriver'
elif sys.platform == "darwin": cd = '/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)


link = "https://sensortower.com/ios/rankings/top/iphone/us/games?date=2021-07-12"
driver.get(link)
driver.set_window_size(600,1000)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

tmpElem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")))
tmpElem.click() 

tmpElem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Top Grossing']")))
tmpElem.click()
```

But with that i only get the following error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\Upwork\MT\scrapeSensorTower.py", line 78, in <module>
    tmpElem.click()
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="universal-button-text" data-bind="text: $data.name">...</span> is not clickable at point (243, 434). Other element would receive the click: <div class="shadowed-st content rankings-table-container flex-span-12">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

Any ideas how i am able to press this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing the `.click()` JavaScript method on the element:

Replace:

```
tmpElem.click()
```

With:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', tmpElem)
```

Comment: Hello - yes this seems to work work, thank you very much - but what means "executing the Javascript method" on the element? What is the difference to the "normal" .click()?

Comment: Hello, the JavaScript is the frontend code that always runs in your browser, even without Selenium. The driver will attempt to click the element in the same way a user does, however the JavaScript has full control over the DOM. If you use developer tools, you will find that if you try the .click() method on an element in the console, that it would be clicked. e.g. document.getElementById('my-button').click()

Answer (score 0):

As I see the element matching the `//span[text()='Top Grossing']` locator is not really clickable. It is not a kind of button etc rather that some element containing that text. So when clicking on it some other element, it's parent element is actually receiving the click.
I'm not sure this is the element you need to click.